# iterate through boost property tree

Tags: xml, boost, boost-propertytree

I'm iterating over an XML document using boost property
tree and storing the results in a struct. The issue I have is that I can
only get to the first "item" nodes and can't access the second "item"
nodes. I was hoping someone would point out where I've made a mistake.

My program output looks like this (you can see items are missing.. there
is no cookie2, candy2 or chocolate2 items shown):

```
jar : snAcks
snack : coOkie
item : cooKie1
snack : canDy
item : caNdy1
snack : cHocolate
item : choColate1
```

Here's the xml file:

```
<root>
    <jar name="snAcks">
        <snack name="coOkie">
           <item name="cooKie1"></item>
           <item name="cookIe2"></item>
        </snack>
        <snack name="canDy">
           <item name="caNdy1"></item>
           <item name="candY2"></item>
        </snack>
        <snack name="cHocolate">
           <item name="choColate1"></item>
           <item name="chocOlate2"></item>
        </snack>
    </jar>
</root>
```

Here's the source code:

```
void parse_xml( boost::property_tree::iptree const& pt )
{
    BOOST_FOREACH( boost::property_tree::iptree::value_type const& v, pt.get_child("root.jar") )
    {
        // Show jar
        if ( boost::iequals( v.first, "<xmlattr>" ) )
        {
            std::cout << "jar : " << v.second.get<std::string>("NaME") << std::endl;
        }

        if ( boost::iequals( v.first, "snack" ) )
        {
            // Show snack
            std::cout << "snack : " << v.second.get<std::string>("<xmlattr>.name")  << std::endl;

            try
            {
                BOOST_FOREACH( boost::property_tree::iptree::value_type const& val, v.second.get_child("item") )
                {
                    if ( boost::iequals( val.first, "<xmlattr>" ) ) {
                        // Show item
                        std::cout << "item : " << val.second.get<std::string>("nAmE")  << std::endl;
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_path& e)
            {
                // Show what caused exception
                std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for taking time to read this. I think I've made a simple
mistake, but cannot understand where.

Comment: I added a bounty. I'd really like to know what I'm doing wrong here or if I need to look at other xml libraries. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Maybe `v.second.get_child("item")` should just be `v.second`, or `v.second.get_child("snack")`: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794418/boost-property-tree-and-xml-parsing-problems) seems similar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured it out, but this is not what i would call an intuitive xml-parser library.

```
void parse_xml( boost::property_tree::iptree const& pt )
{
    BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::iptree::value_type const& v, pt.get_child("root.jar"))
    {
        // Show jar
        if ( boost::iequals( v.first, "<xmlattr>" ) ) {
            std::cout << "jar : " << v.second.get<std::string>("NaME") << std::endl;
        }

        if ( boost::iequals( v.first, "snack" ) )
        {
            BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::iptree::value_type const& val, v.second)
            {
                // Show snack
                if ( boost::iequals( val.first, "<xmlattr>" ) ) {
                    std::cout << "snack : " << val.second.get<std::string>("name")  << std::endl;
                }

                if ( boost::iequals(val.first, "item") )
                {
                    BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::iptree::value_type const& val2, val.second)
                    if ( boost::iequals( val2.first, "<xmlattr>" ) ) {
                        // Show item
                        std::cout << "item : " << val2.second.get<std::string>("nAmE")  << std::endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you compare the two code snippets you can see that mine is bit more regularly structured.

1. Loop over all nodes
2. process the `<xmlattr>` node
3. process the "real" node.
4. repeat from step 1. inside that node.

Comment: Thanks! That works. I can't award the bounty for awhile, but as soon as I can, it's yours. I really appreciate your time and advice!

Comment: "this is not what i would call an intuitive xml-parser library." That's because property-tree *is not an XML parser!* That's not what it is for. It's designed for creating trees of properties and persisting them over time. You are *not* supposed to feed it arbitrary XML that it didn't generate. You're not supposed to use it as a quick-and-dirty XML parser.

Comment: If you want a simple way to parse XML files in C++ I would recommend using libxml2 in conjunction with this c++ wrapper https://github.com/filipenf/libxml-cpp-wrapper